# How to fix requests and zipp incompatible when installing apache-airflow?

Tags: airflow

I'm following the video tutorial [Apache Airflow Installation on Windows 10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CLUhL6-RpqU&ab_channel=BigDatapediaML%26DS) to install apache-airflow. When I do `pip install apache-airflow` in WSL2 Ubuntu, it hints

```
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-http 2.0.3 has requirement requests>=2.26.0, but you'll have requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: importlib-resources 5.4.0 has requirement zipp>=3.1.0; python_version < "3.10", but you'll have zipp 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
```

Giving more details, it looks like this

```
Collecting apache-airflow
  Downloading apache_airflow-2.2.4-py3-none-any.whl (5.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 5.3 MB 4.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=0.9.3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.8)
Collecting markdown<4.0,>=2.5.2
  Downloading Markdown-3.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 97 kB 4.4 MB/s
Collecting sqlalchemy<1.4.0,>=1.3.18
  Downloading SQLAlchemy-1.3.24-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (1.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.3 MB 5.2 MB/s
Collecting connexion[flask,swagger-ui]>=2.10.0
  Downloading connexion-2.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 94 kB 2.7 MB/s
Collecting unicodecsv>=0.14.1
  Downloading unicodecsv-0.14.1.tar.gz (10 kB)
Collecting docutils<0.17
  Downloading docutils-0.16-py2.py3-none-any.whl (548 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 548 kB 8.2 MB/s
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-ftp
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_ftp-2.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-http
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_http-2.0.3-py3-none-any.whl (21 kB)
Collecting alembic<2.0,>=1.5.1
  Downloading alembic-1.7.6-py3-none-any.whl (210 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 210 kB 5.9 MB/s
Collecting iso8601>=0.1.12
  Downloading iso8601-1.0.2-py3-none-any.whl (9.7 kB)
Collecting setproctitle<2,>=1.1.8
  Downloading setproctitle-1.2.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (36 kB)
Collecting argcomplete<3.0,>=1.10
  Downloading argcomplete-2.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Collecting flask<2.0,>=1.1.0
  Downloading Flask-1.1.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (94 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 94 kB 3.3 MB/s
Collecting clickclick>=1.2
  Downloading clickclick-20.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.4 kB)
Collecting tabulate<0.9,>=0.7.5
  Downloading tabulate-0.8.9-py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Collecting flask-wtf<0.15,>=0.14.3
  Downloading Flask_WTF-0.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting httpx
  Downloading httpx-0.22.0-py3-none-any.whl (84 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 84 kB 2.3 MB/s
Collecting flask-appbuilder==3.4.4
  Downloading Flask_AppBuilder-3.4.4-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.9 MB 10.5 MB/s
Collecting termcolor>=1.1.0
  Downloading termcolor-1.1.0.tar.gz (3.9 kB)
Collecting marshmallow-oneofschema>=2.0.1
  Downloading marshmallow_oneofschema-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting werkzeug>=1.0.1,~=1.0
  Downloading Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 298 kB 9.9 MB/s
Collecting pygments<3.0,>=2.0.1
  Downloading Pygments-2.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 5.7 MB/s
Collecting rich>=9.2.0
  Downloading rich-11.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (217 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 217 kB 11.7 MB/s
Collecting flask-session<=0.4.0,>=0.3.1
  Downloading Flask_Session-0.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2.13
  Downloading Deprecated-1.2.13-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Collecting markupsafe<2.1.0,>=1.1.1
  Downloading MarkupSafe-2.0.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (30 kB)
Collecting lockfile>=0.12.2
  Downloading lockfile-0.12.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting dill<0.4,>=0.2.2
  Downloading dill-0.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (86 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 86 kB 4.5 MB/s
Collecting psutil<6.0.0,>=4.2.0
  Downloading psutil-5.9.0-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (283 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 283 kB 10.3 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: blinker in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.4)
Collecting croniter>=0.3.17
  Downloading croniter-1.3.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting pendulum~=2.0
  Downloading pendulum-2.1.2-cp38-cp38-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (155 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 155 kB 11.1 MB/s
Collecting importlib-metadata>=1.7; python_version < "3.9"
  Downloading importlib_metadata-4.11.2-py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy-jsonfield~=1.0
  Downloading SQLAlchemy_JSONField-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-imap
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_imap-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting cattrs!=1.7.*,~=1.1; python_version > "3.6"
  Downloading cattrs-1.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (29 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: jinja2<3.1,>=2.10.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (2.10.1)
Collecting python-nvd3~=0.15.0
  Downloading python-nvd3-0.15.0.tar.gz (31 kB)
Collecting gunicorn>=20.1.0
  Downloading gunicorn-20.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 79 kB 7.5 MB/s
Collecting itsdangerous<2.0,>=1.1.0
  Downloading itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Collecting flask-caching<2.0.0,>=1.5.0
  Downloading Flask_Caching-1.10.1-py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources~=5.2; python_version < "3.9"
  Downloading importlib_resources-5.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (28 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pyjwt<3 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (1.7.1)
Collecting python3-openid~=3.2
  Downloading python3_openid-3.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 133 kB 11.3 MB/s
Collecting tenacity>=6.2.0
  Downloading tenacity-8.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (24 kB)
Collecting wtforms<3.0.0
  Downloading WTForms-2.3.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (169 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 169 kB 13.4 MB/s
Collecting python-dateutil<3,>=2.3
  Downloading python_dateutil-2.8.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (247 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 247 kB 25.6 MB/s
Collecting colorlog<7.0,>=4.0.2
  Downloading colorlog-6.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Collecting attrs<21.0,>=20.0
  Downloading attrs-20.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (49 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 49 kB 6.1 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: jsonschema~=3.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from apache-airflow) (3.2.0)
Collecting apache-airflow-providers-sqlite
  Downloading apache_airflow_providers_sqlite-2.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting flask-login<0.5,>=0.3
  Downloading Flask-Login-0.4.1.tar.gz (14 kB)
Collecting packaging>=14.0
  Downloading packaging-21.3-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 5.6 MB/s
Collecting python-slugify<5.0,>=3.0.0
  Downloading python-slugify-4.0.1.tar.gz (11 kB)
Collecting python-daemon>=2.2.4
  Downloading python_daemon-2.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (35 kB)
Collecting lazy-object-proxy
  Downloading lazy_object_proxy-1.7.1-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (60 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 60 kB 4.9 MB/s
Collecting graphviz>=0.12
  Downloading graphviz-0.19.1-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 46 kB 3.9 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.9.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from connexion[flask,swagger-ui]>=2.10.0->apache-airflow) (2.22.0)
Collecting inflection<0.6,>=0.3.1
  Downloading inflection-0.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.5 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML<6,>=5.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from connexion[flask,swagger-ui]>=2.10.0->apache-airflow) (5.3.1)
Collecting swagger-ui-bundle<0.1,>=0.0.2; extra == "swagger-ui"
  Downloading swagger_ui_bundle-0.0.9-py3-none-any.whl (6.2 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.2 MB 8.2 MB/s
Collecting Mako
  Downloading Mako-1.1.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (75 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 75 kB 5.2 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: click<8.0,>=5.1 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from flask<2.0,>=1.1.0->apache-airflow) (7.0)
Collecting httpcore<0.15.0,>=0.14.5
  Downloading httpcore-0.14.7-py3-none-any.whl (68 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 68 kB 7.6 MB/s
Collecting charset-normalizer
  Downloading charset_normalizer-2.0.12-py3-none-any.whl (39 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from httpx->apache-airflow) (2019.11.28)
Collecting rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3
  Downloading rfc3986-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (31 kB)
Collecting sniffio
  Downloading sniffio-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy<3,>=2.4
  Downloading Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama<1,>=0.3.9 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from flask-appbuilder==3.4.4->apache-airflow) (0.4.3)
Collecting Flask-OpenID<2,>=1.2.5
  Downloading Flask_OpenID-1.3.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting apispec[yaml]<4,>=3.3
  Downloading apispec-3.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (27 kB)
Collecting prison<1.0.0,>=0.2.1
  Downloading prison-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.8 kB)
Collecting sqlalchemy-utils<1,>=0.32.21
  Downloading SQLAlchemy_Utils-0.38.2-py3-none-any.whl (100 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 100 kB 10.1 MB/s
Collecting Flask-Babel<3,>=1
  Downloading Flask_Babel-2.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 kB)
Collecting marshmallow-enum<2,>=1.5.1
  Downloading marshmallow_enum-1.5.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting email-validator<2,>=1.0.5
  Downloading email_validator-1.1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
Collecting marshmallow<4,>=3
  Downloading marshmallow-3.14.1-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 47 kB 5.5 MB/s
Collecting marshmallow-sqlalchemy<0.27.0,>=0.22.0
  Downloading marshmallow_sqlalchemy-0.26.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting Flask-JWT-Extended<4,>=3.18
  Downloading Flask-JWT-Extended-3.25.1.tar.gz (32 kB)
Collecting commonmark<0.10.0,>=0.9.0
  Downloading commonmark-0.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (51 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 51 kB 5.4 MB/s
Collecting cachelib
  Downloading cachelib-0.6.0-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Collecting wrapt<2,>=1.10
  Downloading wrapt-1.13.3-cp38-cp38-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl (84 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 84 kB 3.4 MB/s
Collecting pytzdata>=2020.1
  Downloading pytzdata-2020.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (489 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 489 kB 12.5 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from importlib-metadata>=1.7; python_version < "3.9"->apache-airflow) (1.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from gunicorn>=20.1.0->apache-airflow) (45.2.0)
Collecting defusedxml
  Downloading defusedxml-0.7.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from python-dateutil<3,>=2.3->apache-airflow) (1.14.0)
Collecting pyparsing!=3.0.5,>=2.0.2
  Downloading pyparsing-3.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (98 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 98 kB 4.0 MB/s
Collecting text-unidecode>=1.3
  Downloading text_unidecode-1.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 78 kB 6.7 MB/s
Collecting anyio==3.*
  Downloading anyio-3.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (79 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 79 kB 4.7 MB/s
Collecting h11<0.13,>=0.11
  Downloading h11-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 54 kB 3.8 MB/s
Requirement already satisfied: idna; extra == "idna2008" in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from rfc3986[idna2008]<2,>=1.3->httpx->apache-airflow) (2.8)
Collecting Babel>=2.3
  Downloading Babel-2.9.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.8 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 8.8 MB 21.7 MB/s
Collecting pytz
  Downloading pytz-2021.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (503 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 503 kB 21.2 MB/s
Collecting dnspython>=1.15.0
  Downloading dnspython-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (266 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 266 kB 26.6 MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: unicodecsv, termcolor, python-nvd3, flask-login, python-slugify, Flask-JWT-Extended
  Building wheel for unicodecsv (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for unicodecsv: filename=unicodecsv-0.14.1-py3-none-any.whl size=10766 sha256=041a76495b159edc931156fbf5ce864026f5437b034a00fe6593eb04e26577fe
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/35/dd/44/ccb37563a01457f5de74ccedccaee81b01a53e12addeab5e0f
  Building wheel for termcolor (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for termcolor: filename=termcolor-1.1.0-py3-none-any.whl size=4830 sha256=9ee238e7b8934df5abda27b7815fc08956944b377e8974f15cb18652a72ae37e
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/a0/16/9c/5473df82468f958445479c59e784896fa24f4a5fc024b0f501
  Building wheel for python-nvd3 (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for python-nvd3: filename=python_nvd3-0.15.0-py3-none-any.whl size=38155 sha256=276e9947c5aade93eec21e7741a55eebbae487447ba06afc4179b4af81782081
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/8c/92/61/c1d567a155a1f15d2e1a633eef32ed3a7c7906c323d49fa3a2
  Building wheel for flask-login (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for flask-login: filename=Flask_Login-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=15935 sha256=2fcba8ea3764610028b8336bc459902ae9872a56e3c7f0f7d16017ce5f0af0dd
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/ec/8e/42/16110a8b4f17e4ef4bd0abd42969fc1fc38229348de9f071df
  Building wheel for python-slugify (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for python-slugify: filename=python_slugify-4.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=6767 sha256=64f464b23ded262fa12431f9340a54449b5ded9879192447007aac61aa918056
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/91/4d/4f/e740a68c215791688c46c4d6251770a570e8dfea91af1acb5c
  Building wheel for Flask-JWT-Extended (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for Flask-JWT-Extended: filename=Flask_JWT_Extended-3.25.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=21599 sha256=8c193d8fc923e74fa994887d63d7004d99f530eb42897b77bda49d2b332a08d2
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/00/60/4a/7fc484ed75cc2baea756f0a3d07aa2065d09688d940c6fac1e
Successfully built unicodecsv termcolor python-nvd3 flask-login python-slugify Flask-JWT-Extended
ERROR: apache-airflow-providers-http 2.0.3 has requirement requests>=2.26.0, but you'll have requests 2.22.0 which is incompatible.
ERROR: importlib-resources 5.4.0 has requirement zipp>=3.1.0; python_version < "3.10", but you'll have zipp 1.0.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: importlib-metadata, markdown, sqlalchemy, werkzeug, inflection, clickclick, itsdangerous, flask, swagger-ui-bundle, connexion, unicodecsv, docutils, apache-airflow-providers-ftp, apache-airflow-providers-http, importlib-resources, markupsafe, Mako, alembic, iso8601, setproctitle, argcomplete, tabulate, wtforms, flask-wtf, sniffio, anyio, h11, httpcore, charset-normalizer, rfc3986, httpx, Flask-SQLAlchemy, defusedxml, python3-openid, Flask-OpenID, apispec, prison, sqlalchemy-utils, pytz, Babel, Flask-Babel, marshmallow, marshmallow-enum, dnspython, email-validator, python-dateutil, flask-login, marshmallow-sqlalchemy, Flask-JWT-Extended, flask-appbuilder, termcolor, marshmallow-oneofschema, pygments, commonmark, rich, cachelib, flask-session, wrapt, deprecated, lockfile, dill, psutil, croniter, pytzdata, pendulum, sqlalchemy-jsonfield, apache-airflow-providers-imap, attrs, cattrs, text-unidecode, python-slugify, python-nvd3, gunicorn, flask-caching, tenacity, colorlog, apache-airflow-providers-sqlite, pyparsing, packaging, python-daemon, lazy-object-proxy, graphviz, apache-airflow
  Attempting uninstall: importlib-metadata
    Found existing installation: importlib-metadata 1.5.0
    Not uninstalling importlib-metadata at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'importlib-metadata'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Attempting uninstall: markupsafe
    Found existing installation: MarkupSafe 1.1.0
    Not uninstalling markupsafe at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'MarkupSafe'. No files were found to uninstall.
  Attempting uninstall: attrs
    Found existing installation: attrs 19.3.0
    Not uninstalling attrs at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
    Can't uninstall 'attrs'. No files were found to uninstall.
Successfully installed Babel-2.9.1 Flask-Babel-2.0.0 Flask-JWT-Extended-3.25.1 Flask-OpenID-1.3.0 Flask-SQLAlchemy-2.5.1 Mako-1.1.6 alembic-1.7.6 anyio-3.5.0 apache-airflow-2.2.4 apache-airflow-providers-ftp-2.0.1 apache-airflow-providers-http-2.0.3 apache-airflow-providers-imap-2.2.0 apache-airflow-providers-sqlite-2.1.0 apispec-3.3.2 argcomplete-2.0.0 attrs-20.3.0 cachelib-0.6.0 cattrs-1.10.0 charset-normalizer-2.0.12 clickclick-20.10.2 colorlog-6.6.0 commonmark-0.9.1 connexion-2.12.0 croniter-1.3.4 defusedxml-0.7.1 deprecated-1.2.13 dill-0.3.4 dnspython-2.2.0 docutils-0.16 email-validator-1.1.3 flask-1.1.4 flask-appbuilder-3.4.4 flask-caching-1.10.1 flask-login-0.4.1 flask-session-0.4.0 flask-wtf-0.14.3 graphviz-0.19.1 gunicorn-20.1.0 h11-0.12.0 httpcore-0.14.7 httpx-0.22.0 importlib-metadata-4.11.2 importlib-resources-5.4.0 inflection-0.5.1 iso8601-1.0.2 itsdangerous-1.1.0 lazy-object-proxy-1.7.1 lockfile-0.12.2 markdown-3.3.6 markupsafe-2.0.1 marshmallow-3.14.1 marshmallow-enum-1.5.1 marshmallow-oneofschema-3.0.1 marshmallow-sqlalchemy-0.26.1 packaging-21.3 pendulum-2.1.2 prison-0.2.1 psutil-5.9.0 pygments-2.11.2 pyparsing-3.0.7 python-daemon-2.3.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 python-nvd3-0.15.0 python-slugify-4.0.1 python3-openid-3.2.0 pytz-2021.3 pytzdata-2020.1 rfc3986-1.5.0 rich-11.2.0 setproctitle-1.2.2 sniffio-1.2.0 sqlalchemy-1.3.24 sqlalchemy-jsonfield-1.0.0 sqlalchemy-utils-0.38.2 swagger-ui-bundle-0.0.9 tabulate-0.8.9 tenacity-8.0.1 termcolor-1.1.0 text-unidecode-1.3 unicodecsv-0.14.1 werkzeug-1.0.1 wrapt-1.13.3 wtforms-2.3.3
```

Comment: what is your python version?

Comment: @devesh `pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)`

Comment: ok try install pip install zipp==3.7.0
pip install requests==2.27.1 and then pip install apache-airflow

Comment: I ran into this trying to install poetry also - @devesh nailed it. Ubuntu is actually the problem, on 20.04 LTS for example, the Ubuntu repo installs `python3-zipp 1.0.0-1`, so by default the version of zipp provided is incompatible. Use `pip install` commands as per @devesh above and it overrides the Ubuntu package and solved the failing requirement for me.

Answer (score 4):

Update system:
$ **sudo apt-get update**

Install python3-zipp:
$ **sudo apt-get install python3-zipp**

Install Airflow:
$ **pip3 install apache-airflow**